# How can I conditionally define a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following script:

```
if (false)​ {
    function foo() {
        alert("FOO");
    }
}
foo(); // alerts "FOO"
```

As you can see, the function `foo` is defined and works even though the condition for the `if` fails.

The reason I want to do this is that I am developing an extension for InDesign and I made a script called utilities.jsx which holds various functions which are used in other scripts. In all the scripts that need these functions, I simply use:

```
app.doScript(File(scriptsFile.parent.fsName + "/t_utilities.jsx"), ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT);
```

which defines all the functions I need and then I can use them. Now, since this script will be called multiple times by various files in an unpredictable order (the user decides), I thought I might only define the functions if they haven't been defined before (if utilities.jsx hasn't run yet). Kind of like `require_once` in php.

I was thinking of something like the following, but that doesn't work as the functions are defined every time the script is run:`

```
var utilitiesHasRun;
if (utilitiesHasRun !== true) {
  // define all the functions
  // ...
  utilitiesHasRun = true;
}
```

Are there any other options?

Comment: Your first code snippet isn't technically valid because function declarations aren't allowed within blocks. It only works at all because all major browsers implement extensions to the ECMAScript spec to deal with this case.

Comment: And to continue @TimDown's comment, your first snippet will actually throw a SyntaxError if it's part of strict mode code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To assure your function has not been defined before, use :

```
if ( typeof yourFunctionName == 'undefined' ) {
  yourFunctionName = function( params ) {
    // your code here
  };
}
```

Comment: This will throw an error if `yourFunctionName` is not defined initially. A `typeof yourFunctionName == 'undefined'` would work though.

Answer (score 20):

You can make them function *expressions* instead of function *declarations*:

```
if (false)​ {
    var foo = function () {
        alert("FOO");
    };
}
foo(); //TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Note that in the above code, `foo` is still accessible even though the condition evaluated to false. This is because *function-scoped declarations* (both function and `var`) are hoisted to the top of the scope in which they are declared. However, *assignments* happen at the point in the code where they appear.

What the above code is effectively doing is this:

```
var foo; //No assignment, foo is undefined
if (false)​ {
    foo = function () {
        alert("FOO");
    };
}
foo(); //TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**Warning** - Named function expressions are still hoisted in Internet Explorer 8 and below (this is a bug in IE). Obviously this is only a potential problem if you need to support old browsers.

Comment: +1: Very concise. I didn't realise that function declarations still hoisted, thought it was only function expressions, but now I see the subtle difference!

Comment: +1 Ahh, hoisting. Thanks for explaining this. I chose Sirko's answer as it doesn't produce an error, but your solution also works if you simply stick the call to foo (`foo()`) in a try block, preventing the error from breaking the script.

Comment: Also a bug in firefox apparently

Answer (score 3):

You can use function pointers to reassign the function as needed.

```
var myFunctionPointer = function { alert("Default"); };
if (condition) {
    myFunctionPointer = function { alert("true"); };
}
else {
    myFunctionPointer = function { alert("false"); };
}
myFunctionPointer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create a full API based on a function that return an object containing methods which are finally call to the minor JS functions. Extensions can interact with JS files with an embedded class. I think I gave you the link to the cookbook. So what you can do is declare an object in AS3 and check for some property like :

```
public var jsAPI:Object = {};
```

the js code would be

```
var jsAPI = function() {
    return {
        hasBeenLoaded:false,
        myMethod1:function(){},
    }
}
```

Then if you need to use a JS function in AS3, you can check some flag like :

```
if ( jsAPI.hasBeenLoaded ){ … }
else { //loads the API via new API() }
```