# How to change clicked image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two types of images and I named them **xxxxx.jpg**(1st) and **xxxxxNoWall.jpg**(2nd). 
I would like to make my page in a way that the 1st version is displayed normally, but when you click on it, the modal will show the 2nd version.  
However, so far I'm only able to make the modal display the same image as I clicked on. I guess the problem is somewhere in JavaScript where I can add "**NoWall.jpg**" behind the name of the original element?
Can somebody help me with it, please?
HTML:

```
    <div id="modal01" class="modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <img id="img01" style="max-width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
   <script>
    
    if(window.innerWidth > 768){
    function onClick(element) {
      document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
      document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
    }} else {
    function onClick(element) {
      document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "none";
    }}
    
    </script>
```

thanks very much!

Comment: A side note,  you cannot conditionally define a  named function. The last definition wins even if the code is never run. See https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/eLrf3kxj/1/ If you really need this in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035071/227299

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about "to define functions".., but thanks, I will look into it!

Comment: You have two definitions of the same `onClickFunction`, you are trying to define them conditionally, which doesn't work. It's not required for this solution but you should understand what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well none of your code is changing `xxxxx.jpg` to `xxxxxNoWall.jpg`.
Is this all the code you have?

You can use [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), for example:

```js
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src.replace(/([^/]+)\.([^.]+)$/, '$1NoWall.$2');
```

This adds "NoWall" before the file extension.
The first parameter of `.replace()` is a regular expression. In this case it works like this:
https://regex101.com/r/0u9WUe/1

Comment: Hey, thanks very much! It perfectly resolved my problem, although I have no idea what all that in the brackets mean but now I think I'm just gonna look into some .replace() tutorials!

Comment: Yes that is a regular expression. These can get complicated. I'll update the answer with an explanation link. Feel free to learn about regular expressions on your own terms.

Comment: excellent! Thanks again very much, there's always so much to learn!